# How to create a custom layer to get and manipulate gradients in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to implement the gradient projections technique from [Mitigating Unwanted Biases with Adversarial Learning](http://m-mitchell.com/papers/Adversarial_Bias_Mitigation.pdf)

The model architecture is

- 1) Input layer
- 2) Dense fixed length layer
- 3) Custom gradient project layer

  - 4a) Task 1 layers
  - 4b) Task 2 layers (adversarial task)

I would like to manipulate the gradients from task 1 and task 2 with a custom layer (3). Currently I plan to have something like this in the call of a custom layer

```
@tf.RegisterGradient('blah')
def proj_gradients(op, grad):
    return grad[0] - grad[1]

g = K.get_session().graph
with g.gradient_override_map({'Identity': 'blah'}):
    y = tf.identity(X)
```

Is there a more intuitive Keras way for doing this?

Comment: There is a link [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20630) I hope it can help. There is also a good example [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/generative_examples/text_generation.ipynb#scrollTo=d4tSNwymzf-q)

Answer (score 1):

[tf.custom_gradient](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) is the best tool to use here. It lets you define the gradient function at the call site, has a nicer interface than the override map, and works well with eager execution.