# Using a custom step activation function in Keras results in “'tuple' object has no attribute '_keras_shape'” error. How to resolve this?

Tags: python, keras, gradient, activation-function

I'm trying to implement a binary custom activation function in the output layer of a Keras model.

This is my trial:

```
def binary_activation(x):
    ones = tf.ones(tf.shape(x), dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype)
    zeros = tf.zeros(tf.shape(x), dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype)
    def grad(dy):
        return dy
    return switch(x > 0.5, ones, zeros), grad
```

Similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632757/using-a-custom-step-activation-function-in-keras-results-in-an-operation-has-n).
But I get the following error back:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/home/marlon/Área de Trabalho/omj_project/predicting_change.py", line 85, in 
model = baseline_model()

File "/home/marlon/Área de Trabalho/omj_project/predicting_change.py", line 80, in baseline_model
model.add(Dense(1, activation=binary_activation))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 181, in add
output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 497, in **call**
arguments=user_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 565, in _add_inbound_node
output_tensors[i]._keras_shape = output_shapes[i]

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_keras_shape'

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code is slightly different to the one in the other question, these small details matter, like you must not use numpy functions in an activation, and you should provide the code that uses this activation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. In fact, the numpy method was a mistake, but it called my attention to another missing detail @tf.custom_gradient. Now it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need add

```
@tf.custom_gradient
```

on top of your code like other comment that you mentioned.

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def binary_activation(x):
    ones = tf.ones(tf.shape(x), dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype)
    
    zeros = tf.zeros(tf.shape(x), dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype)
    res = tf.keras.backend.switch(x > 0.5, ones, zeros)
    def grad(dy):
        return dy
    return res, grad
```

Comment: Exactly it! Thanks!

Comment: Also I have deleted converting to numpy. Welcome.